# modify header view of NSTableview

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I would like to "pimp" my table view header
It should get a height of 60.0.

I tried this:

```
myTableView.headerView!.frame.size.height = 60
```

It will be higher, but the "content" will keep the same size:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the height of NSTableHeaderView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561004/how-to-increase-the-height-of-nstableheaderview)

Comment: yes, but the "solutions" in this topic are the same, which I tried

Comment: The header view is an NSView object.  It has nothing to do with table view headers.

Comment: okay, and that means for me?

Comment: Read the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14704679/4244136). Other solution: if the columns are fixed then you can switch the header off and add your own.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest assign frame instead of height.

```
 NSRect frame = tableView.headerView.frame;
frame.size.height = 26;
tableView.headerView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: this will be the same result like my picture shows :(

Comment: if u want to resize your content as per height and you are using autolayout then use `layoutSubviews()` on headerview.
And if you are using hardcoded frames while creating headerview subviews then you need to resize them all manually.

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var x: NSTableHeaderView! x.frame.size.height = 60;
        x.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded();` I tried this. but it doesn't work. what do i wrong?